# StringUtil indexOf() equivalent postgreSQL query

Tags: java, postgresql, indexof, string-utils

I need to implement stringUtils Class indexOf() method in postgresql.

Lets say I have a `table` in which `url` is one of the column.

`url : "http://paypal-info.com/home.webapps.cgi-bin-limit/webscr.cmd-login-submit"`

My requirement is to find the index of the 3rd occurence of '/' in the above url and do substring and take only `paypal-info.com`  host name in `Postgresql Query`

Any idea on implementing this would be grateful.
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried split_part method?

```
SELECT split_part('http://paypal-info.com/home.webapps.cgi-bin-limit/webscr.cmd-login-submit', '/', 3)
```

Result:

```
split_part
paypal-info.com
```

For other string functions try this doc:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html

Edit: as for indexOf itself I don't know any built-in postgres solution. But using two string functions You can achieve it like this:

```
SELECT strpos('http://paypal-info.com/home.webapps.cgi-bin-limit/webscr.cmd-login-submit', split_part('http://paypal-info.com/home.webapps.cgi-bin-limit/webscr.cmd-login-submit', '/', 4)) - 1 as index_of;
```

Comment: That looks great Michal. but how to get the indexOf 3rd '/' alone without splitting. My aim is to take the index? how can we do that?

Comment: @sri Sorry, I focused on this part of the question:
"and do substring and take only paypal-info.com host name in Postgresql Query". And so i did take the the host name out.
As for finding the third occurence of the '/' I don't think there is a simple solution in postgres. You would have to nest string functions.

Comment: @sri - I've edited the answer with some workaround - I don't know if it's ok for you.
I used the position of the forth substring taken from the aforementioned `split_part()`.

Comment: @sri - you can wrap this workaround from my edit in your own util function, and you'll have the result you need.

Answer (score 4):

The [string functions and operators section of the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html) is the equivalent of `String.indexOf`, e.g.

```
select position('/' in 'http://paypal-info.com/home.webapps.cgi-bin-limit/webscr.cmd-login-submit');
```

however it doesn't offer the option to get the n'th occurrence.

You're really approaching this all wrong. You should use proper URL parsing code to extract the host portion, not attempt to roll your own or use regex / splitting / string mangling.

PostgreSQL doesn't have a native URL/URI type, but its procedural languages do and it's trivial to wrap suitable functions. e.g. with PL/Python:

```
create language plpythonu;
create or replace function urlhost(url text) returns text 
language plpythonu 
immutable strict
as $$
import urlparse
return urlparse.urlparse(url).netloc
$$;
```

then:

```
regress=# select urlhost('http://paypal-info.com/home.webapps.cgi-bin-limit/webscr.cmd-login-submit');
     urlhost     
-----------------
 paypal-info.com
(1 row)
```

If you'd prefer to use PL/Perl, PL/V8, or whatever, that's fine.

For best performance, you could write a simple C function and expose that as an extension.

Comment: I'm not sure your definition of "wrong" is correct.

Comment: @Vlad Well, it's not as bad as parsing HTML with regex, but why roll your own when you can use well tested, pre-written code?

Comment: I rather meant that it depends on specific requirements.

Comment: @Vlad PL/Perl or PL/Python are part of the core PostgreSQL distribution. Python's `urlparse` is part of Python's core. Pretty safe bet IMO, and you can always fall back to one of the `split_part` solutions already offered by others if you really needed to for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace 3 with N to get the index of the Nth '/' in a given string

```
SELECT length(substring('http://asd/asd', '(([^/]*/){3})')) - 1
```

To extract the host name from url you can use

```
SELECT substring('http://asd.com:234/qwe', 'http://([^:]+).*/')
```

Tested here: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/d41d8/2532/0)

Comment: Sorry Vlad both queries doesn't work. I dont know why. I dont get any outputs

Comment: What version is your postgresql?

Comment: I havent tested it on a database, will try later when I can.

Comment: @sri Indeed the reg expressions had mistakes... Corrected them now. Also added a fiddle.

Comment: thanks Vlad. the First query do not need -1 otherwise it works.

Comment: Index is normally zero-based, that's why -1. If you want it to be 1-based, then you don't need to do -1 indeed. Btw, is your question answered now? :)